# videoJS HLS not working on Production Server but works in Localhost

Tags: video.js, http-live-streaming

I've been trying to make this videoJS HLS work. It works perfectly when I do it in localhost but when I upload it to the server it gives me "VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) No compatible source was found for this video."

Here's the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Video</title>

  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
 <script src="https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-media-sources/releases/download/v0.1.0/videojs-media-sources.js"></script>
  <script src="https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls/releases/download/v0.11.2/videojs.hls.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Video</h1>

  <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268" 
  data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8" type='application/x-mpegURL'>
  </video>

  <script>
  var player = videojs('my_video_1');
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me if I need to do something with the server to make this work? Thanks

Comment: Figured it out. Version of my videoJS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify if your server has CORS activated.
Go to videojs cors documentation: https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls
and here for test:
http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client